# Dynamic Linq .Select() - How to handle certain null values

Tags: linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic for a project that requires the user to choose which properties will be selected/projected at runtime.

So, I have a query like this:

```
var query = db.Users.Select("New(UserId, Username, Groups.Max(DateInserted) AS DateInserted)");
```

The DateInserted column is not null, but not all users have groups.
So, when a user is returned without groups, I get the following error:

```
"The cast to value type 'DateTime' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."
```

Is there anything I can do in the query?  I cannot make the column nullable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to nullable type DateTime? like this:
`var query = db.Users.Select("New(UserId, Username, DateTime?(Groups.Max(DateInserted)) AS DateInserted)");`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  When I try this, I get the following exception: "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."